# How do I expand page width to handle wider marginparwidths while leaving everything else as it is?

Tags: margins, two-column, geometry, marginpar, todonotes

I would like to be able to use `todonotes` package, but the amount of `marginparwidth` on right and left are relatively small. The space available for margins is too small that I want to increase the page width but without any modifications for anything in the paper (i.e., I just need extra space for margin notes).

The notes are available only to me during preparation or presentation and they are hidden from the general audience. Hence, it is imperative to be able to easily hide the notes and recover the original layout for the audience copy.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=true}

    \geometry{marginparwidth=75pt}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}   

\usepackage{todonotes}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\todosample}{This text is intended as a sample for todo tests} 


\paragraph{My Paragraph}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures.\todo[color=yellow]{\todosample} After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

\paragraph{My Paragraph}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

\paragraph{My Paragraph}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. \todo[color=cyan]{\todosample} Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.



\end{document}
```

@Steven B. Segletes. I appreciate your answer. However, with TeXStudio, the output is as follows

[image]

With Overleaf, I get the correct output. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I extended `\paperwidth` and `\hoffset`, which then made room for a larger `marginparwidth` specification.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=true}

    \geometry{marginparwidth=120pt}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}   

\usepackage{todonotes}
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth+1in\relax
\hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset+.5in\relax

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\todosample}{This text is intended as a sample for todo tests} 


\paragraph{My Paragraph}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures.\todo[color=yellow]{\todosample} After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

\paragraph{My Paragraph}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

\paragraph{My Paragraph}
This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. \todo[color=cyan]{\todosample} Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The note to the right seems to be clipped when I use this code

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh The three dimensional-adjustments to play with are `\paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth+1in\relax`, `\hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset+.5in\relax`, and `\geometry{marginparwidth=120pt}`.  I recommend the `\hoffset` adjustment to always be 1/2 of the `\paperwidth` adjustment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes could you give an example of how to fix the problem of clipped boxes on both the right and the left side?

Comment: @YuShen Just reduce `\geometry{marginparwidth=120pt}` to something slightly smaller.