# Why does TeXstudio generate cropped PDFs?

Tags: margins, texstudio, geometry

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453397/how-do-i-expand-page-width-to-handle-wider-marginparwidths-while-leaving-everyth), I asked about how to add extra margins for todo notes without affecting the original geometry of the page. The answer by Steven B. Segletes is satisfactory, but the output is not as intended with TeXstudio. The PDF generated seems to clip the content so that the page size stays almost the same.

Here is how the output is with the PDF taken as genreated

[image]

Here is how the output is after modifying the page size using an **external** PDF editor

[image]

TeXstudio generates the PDF correctly but crops it to be as close as possible to an A4 paper. Is there a way to force TeXstudio to generate the PDF in its real size and not crop it?

Comment: texstudio is just the editor in which you typed your tex source file, it does not produce pdf at all. Whatever is generated depend on the commands that you run on that tex file such as pdftex  or latex+dvips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for David Carlisle for drawing my attention to how to answer this question.

Go to options --> Configure TeXstudio -> Build. For 'Build & View', choose either asy-pdf-chain or pdf-chain.

[image]

Comment: Unless you are actually using asymptote in your document, I would not use the `asy-pdf-chain`

Comment: What does 'asymptote' mean in LaTeX?

Comment: `asymptote` is a tool to draw complicate things, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote for some examples